# Spring Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

I know there are a lot of question on SO about this already, but most of them refer to XML configurations, I'm using annotations. My IDE is IntelliJ and I'm using Gradle as my build system.

So I have a really simple web service, I want to enable login and register functionality. My DAO looks like this:

```
public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        hibernateTemplate.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return hibernateTemplate.execute(session -> (User)
                session.createCriteria(User.class)
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("username", username))
                        .uniqueResult());
    }
}
```

And my config is this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public IUserDAO userDAO() {
        return new UserDAO();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() {
        return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(getDataSource())
                .addAnnotatedClasses(User.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://example.com:3306/myDatabase");
        dataSource.setUsername("myUser");
        dataSource.setPassword("myUser123");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibTransMan() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }
}
```

I use this in my `RestController` to get the DAO:

```
@Autowired
private IUserDAO userDAO;
```

Executing `findByUsername` works ok and returns the `User` that matches the given username. However, the `addUser` method doesnt work, and gives me this error:

```
Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
```

I've looked around and found that I should add `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` to my function, so I did that (I added it above my `addUser` function, if that's even the right place to put it...), but then I get this error:

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: hibTransMan,transactionManager
```

Can anyone help me with this situation? Also, for any IntelliJ users, the `@Autowired` annotation in my UserDAO is flagged with a warning that says `Autowired members must be defined in the valid spring bean(@Component/@Service,etc.)`. Anyone know why this is happening?

P.S. If anybody is startled by the Lambda expression in my `findByUsername` method, I'm using Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I added the `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` annotation to my `addUser` method, and `@Primary` to my `hibTransMan` method in the `AppConfig` class. However, the warning about `@Autowired` is still there, anyone know why?

Comment: Do you have Spring facet configured in Project Structure? If you don't have it configured, IntelliJ won't know that UserDao is actually used as Spring Bean (which is defined in your AppConfig class) and therefore it will show the warnings.

Comment: I do, yes. At first, it wasn't configured and I got more of these errors, then I set it up and most of them are gone but this one remains. Also, there is an icon next to it "Navigate to autowired dependencies". If I click it it takes me to my AppConfig file, where my `hibernateTemplate` method is defined, as it should.